# Angular UI Grid: how to fill a dropdown filter with real data from database/backend

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

I've been struggling for more than 1 day trying to find a solution to pre-fill angular-ui-grid dropdown with data from the backend. And yes, I've seen many similar questions, but none of them talks about filling a selectOption with real data from backend.

It works fine with a pre-defined array like this: `$scope.tiposArquivoSelecionados = [{ value: 1, label: 'First'}, { value: 2, label: 'Second'}, { value: 3, label: 'Third'}];`

[image]

But when I try to fill the selectOption with data gathered from backend, the selectOption is not displayed. Take a look:

[image]

The data is gathered successfully, the grid is rendered successfully, what makes me think it's a timing problem.

Here is a list of a few workarounds I tried (all failed) to solve the possible timing problem:

- refresh the grid after gathering the data;
- put the columnDefs inside the service success callback
- put a ng-if in the .html to display the grid only if the array.length > 0

None of them worked =/

---

selectOptions array declaration:

```
$scope.tiposArquivoGridSelectOptions = [];
```

Code from the GridOptions.columnDefs:

```
{
  field: 'controleArquivoId',
  name: 'Tipo de Arquivo',
  cellClass: 'ui-grid-cell-padding',
  enableFiltering: true,
  enableSorting: true,
  enableHiding: true,
  filter: {
    type: uiGridConstants.filter.SELECT,
    selectOptions: $scope.tiposArquivoGridSelectOptions,
  },
  sort: {
    direction: uiGridConstants.ASC,
    priority: 3
  }
},
```

In my controller, I have the init() method, which calls the service to gather the data from the backend and fills the selectOption array.

```
AutorizacoesReenvioService.listarTiposArquivoPorAno(moment().year()).then(
  function (success) {
    var responseData = success.data;

    responseData.forEach(function(item) {
      $scope.tiposArquivoGridSelectOptions.push(
        {
          value: item.id,
          label: item.nomeArquivo
        }
      );
    });

    $scope.gridApi.core.refresh();
  },
  function (error) {
    console.error(success.data);
  }
);
```

Comment: I tried using a plunker, but found no problems... There is no need to refresh the grid.
Please check [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/qIeXkkHPzJEClOppwrNN?p=preview). 
The dropdown is toggled by pressing the 'toggle filtering' button.

Comment: Thank you @Remko, but the problem is when I try to fill the dropdown options with data from backend using $http.

Comment: That should not make any difference. Check the plunker again, I changed the toggleFiltering function (makes even less sense now ;), but it still works.
Could you try and make a plunker showing the issue you are having, since I cannot reproduce your problem?